# ¿Qué hace "awk -F: '!(condición)'"?

Tags: linux, unix, awk

Hice un `man` para mas o menos conocer de que se trata el comando `awk` y según la descripción me encontre lo siguiente:

> name: mawk - pattern scanning and text processing language

Así que es un lenguaje que procesa patrones y texto, algo así como un `grep` mejorado.

Según un código de la universidad me dijeron que tenía que explicar ciertos comandos, y me colocaron una lista, entre ellos estaba este comando:

```
awk -F: '!($3 < 512 && $4 < 30)' /etc/passwd
```

Esto me devuelve ciertos directorios y una información algo extraña, estuve analizándolo, y por lo que puedo ver lista unos directorios en especifico, pero no sé de acuerdo a qué ni por qué razón, es decir, ando algo confundido... ¿Qué hace este comando?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

AWK es un lenguaje de programación con el que normalmente se procesan datos en línea de comandos. Es muy versátil y está muy bien pensado para hacer mucho con poco. A mí me encanta :__)

Entendamos este comando:

```
awk -F: '!($3 < 512 && $4 < 30)' /etc/passwd
```

Antes de nada conviene saber que el fichero /etc/passwd conntiene la lista de usuarios existentes en un sistema UNIX. Su formato es una serie de siete valores separados por `:`:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En tu caso, vemos que habla de `$3` y `$4`. Esto quiere decir que va a estar mirando los campos 3.º y 4.º (ID de usuario e ID de grupo, respectivamente).

Por tanto, parece que queremos procesar datos de este fichero y extraer líneas determinadas.

AWK trabaja con registros y campos. En general (y en este caso por ejemplo) un registro es una línea y un campo es lo que se delimita por el separador. `-F:` en este caso nos indica que el separador son los dos puntos, por lo que `hola:que:tal` implicará que `$1=hola`, `$2=que` y `$3=tal`, es decir, los campos se van asignando por orden a medida que se van encontrando los separadores.

- `-F:` indica el separador de campos
- `($3 < 512 && $4 < 30)` simplemente está filtrando aquellos registros cuyo 3.º campo sea menor que 512 y, además, su 4.º sea menor que 30.
- `!( ... )` está negando la condición, por lo que pasamos a tener todos aquellos registros que tengan su 3.º campo >= 512 o bien el 4.º >= 30.

Así, ya tenemos la condición. Pues bien, AWK automáticamente imprime todos los registros (líneas) que cumplen esta condición (si dices `awk '$2=2' fichero` te imprime todas las líneas cuyo 2.º campo es 2, por ejemplo).

Así pues, el programa imprimirá todas las líneas cuyo ID de usuario >= 512 o bien ID de grupo >= 30. Seguramente, aquellos usuarios que no sean de sistema.

Comment: Gracias amigo, te felicito por poder darme una respuesta tan detallada y bien explicada, agradezco tu tiempo, ahora por fin en tiendo que significa, muchas gracias por sí responder a la pregunta en vez de cerrarla.

Comment: No hay de qué. Te animo a probar el comando e intentar variaciones para coger más conocimiento sobre este lenguaje. Para cualquier duda, aquí estamos